How to scrub getServerSideProps between SSR and sending __NEXT_DATA__ to client?
I have large POJO object of live-configuration data that various components on the page may need to access. During the SSR phase, I can provide a way for components to declare their data requirements for key-paths within this object. I would like to have a way so that during SSR the entire object is available to components, but after SSR, we can apply some kind of middleware to the response so that all but the explicitly declared key-paths are scrubbed from this object so that they are not include in NEXT_DATA. How would I do this?
